# SQL Select Max Date with Multiple records

Tags: sql-server, select, date

I am struggling with a query to pull most recent entries.  I have a Notes table that contains the following columns:

```
BusinessDate
ReportGuid
NoteGuid
Note
NoteDate
NoteAddedBy
```

The BusinessDate, ReportGuid and NoteGuid are the PK on the table.  This table allows a specific ReportGuid to have multiple notes per day.  I have another table that contains additional Report info that will be joined and displayed for the users.  I am trying to pull and display only the most recent note entry for each ReportGuid.

I tried using Max(NoteDate) but that is only getting me the latest note added to the table not the latest note for each ReportGuid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

thanks for the help:

```
SELECT N.Note, N.ReportGuid
FROM Tracking.SM_T_Report_Notes N
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT ReportGuid, Max(NoteDate) As NoteDate
    FROM Tracking.SM_T_Report_Notes
    GROUP BY ReportGuid
    ) AS ND
    ON  N.NoteDate = ND.NoteDate
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `group by ReportGuid` and select `Max(NoteDate)`. That will select the maximum of each group.

Comment: That works if I only want ReportGuid and NoteDate but I need all of the columns of data. 

SELECT ReportGuid, Max(NoteDate) As NoteDate
  FROM T.SM_T_Report_Notes
  GROUP BY ReportGuid

Comment: @bluefeet: Oh, ok. In that case you can simply SELECT max(ReportGuid), Max(NoteDate) As NoteDate FROM T.SM_T_Report_Notes GROUP BY ReportGuid