# Select distinct rows with max date with repeated and null values (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've 3 tables. Let's say Root, Detail and Revision

I need to select the distinct codes from Root with the highest revision date, having count that the revision lines may not exist and/or have repeteated values in the date column.

```
Root: idRoot, Code
Detail: idDetail, price, idRoot
Revision: idRevision, date, idDetail
```

So, i've started doing the join query:

```
select code, price, date from Root r 
inner join Detail d on d.idRoot = r.idRoot
left join Revision r on d.idDetail = r.idDetail;
```

Having table results like this:

```
CODE|PRICE|DATE     idRevision
---- ----- -----    -----------
C1    100  2/1/2016      1
C1    120  2/1/2016      3
C1    150  null          2
C1    200  1/1/2016      4
C2    300  null          null
C3    400  3/1/2016      6
```

But what I really need is the next result:

```
CODE|PRICE|DATE     idRevision
---- ----- -----    -----------
C1    120  2/1/2016   3 
C2    300  null      null 
C3    400  3/1/2016   6
```

I've seen several answers for similar cases, but never with null and repeated values:

[Oracle: Taking the record with the max date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898020/oracle-taking-the-record-with-the-max-date)

[Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

[Oracle Select Max Date on Multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761665/oracle-select-max-date-on-multiple-records)

Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select code, price, date
from (select code, price, date,
            row_number() over (partition by code order by date desc nulls last, idRevision desc) as seqnum
      from Root r inner join
           Detail d
           on d.idRoot = r.idRoot left join
           Revision r
           on d.idDetail = r.idDetail
     ) rdr
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: it seems OP wants order max revision for latest date. Shouldn't that be (partition by code order by date desc nulls last, idrevision desc) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. As micklesh said, it should be ordered by date first, but still... ;)